# Issues accessing dialog from resource view

Tags: c++, visual-studio, activex, msdn, activexobject

Ok, I have a Microsoft StatusBar ActiveX control (SP6) within a dialog and for some reason recently when i attempt to access the dialog an error is thrown... The error is "The ActiveX Control "Microsoft StatusBar Control 6.0 (SP6) is not registered on this computer. Register the control and try again.Now i havent come across this issue before ...

What i have tried : 
Powershell -> Regsvr32 /u "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscomctl.ocx" 
This completes successfully...

I then try Powershell -> Regsvr32 "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscomctl.ocx" and this error is thrown -
The module "C:\Windows\SysWOW65\mscomctl.ocx was loaded but the call to DLLRegisterServer failed with error code 0x8002801c. For more information about this problem, search online using the error  cose as a search term.

Now doing as suggested and searching for the error-code didnt bring me any closer to solving the issue.(The error value 0x8002801c means, Error accessing the OLE (Object Linking and Embedding) registry. In an attempt to rectify this based on what i could find online i tried to regsvr32 the mscomct2.ocx to no avail.

No idea why I suddenly find myself plagued by this issue.... Any advice would be greatly appreciated. What am i missing ? I havent stumbled across this issue previously ... up until now.....

Thanks stackoverflow crew !!!!!!

EDIT: I am repairing the visual studio install in a hope that it correctly registers the appropriate activex controls..... Pain in the a$$ but im hoping the issue is resolved. If not i guess i could just install something that requires the control ?? ..

2nd EDIT: I found the controls within  Microsoft Common Controls SP6 pack and after repairing the Visual Studio installation If need be i will simply install the controls and register/de-register them as necessary.....

Answer (score 0):

I repaired the Visual Studio installation and simply did as i suggested i did earlier but with no success. On this occasion it worked and everything is A-ok ! Its often not my code that is the issue its some other little buggy thing affecting my pc or library/symbols/dlls ....

Cheers anyway,